# Understanding a mathematical solution to a debt race question.

Tags: problem-solving, arithmetic-progressions

I was given the following proof (for a method for figuring out the time taken to completely pay of a loan):

[image]

The proof makes sense up until z-(1 + I) = 0.

How did they go from [A<sub>n</sub> - (1 + I)A<sub>n-1</sub>] to [z - (1 + 0)]?

Comment: Maybe there's an assumption $\frac{A_{n}}{A_{n-1}} = z$

Comment: @MattiP.  Wow...now I feel really silly! (Not sarcastic) Thanks!